# Browse excel file then copy data from a browsed file to active file

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to write a macro which you can browse an excel file. Then in the browsed file, search in a sheet by sheet name (3. Variance analysis) then copy datas from this sheet to actual excel sheet (which is also named 3. Variance analysis).

I already got the following code:

```
Sub YOY()
Dim strFileToOpen As String
Dim Wbk_WeeklyTemplate As Workbook
Dim Tgt_ShtNm As String
Dim Src_ShtNm As String

'Choosing an Excel File using File dialog Box and capturing the file path in the variable
strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please select the file to open", FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

'Checking if file is selected
If strFileToOpen = "False" Then
    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set Wbk_WeeklyTemplate = Workbooks.Open(strFileToOpen)
End If

''Refer sheet by Sheet CodeName
Src_ShtNm = SheetName(Wbk_WeeklyTemplate, "3. Variance analysis")
Tgt_ShtNm = SheetName(ThisWorkbook, "3. Variance analysis")

Wbk_WeeklyTemplate.Sheets(Src_ShtNm).Range("D9:E16").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Tgt_ShtNm).Range("M9:N16").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub


''The function SheetName returns the actual name of the sheet by passing sheet code name
Function SheetName(Wb As Workbook, CodeName As String) As String
SheetName = Wb.VBProject.VBComponents(CodeName).Properties("3. Variance analysis").Value
End Function
```

Now I can open a file, but it stopped during copy and paste. It says some error with Function() part.

Comment: hi, the error is in copy or in paste ? can u post the line where the error appears and the exact error ?

Comment: I think I'm confused what the `SheetName` function is supposed to do? You give it the `CodeName` as input and the function itself includes the sheet's name, `"3. Variance analysis"`, so what does it even return?

Comment: If you've already got the workbook and the sheet name, why do you need/want to access the sheets by their codename? (I realize that's your intent but i don't believe that is really what your function is actually returning)